# how can I insert values of sqlite3 database table into NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I have retrieved data from sqlite3 database table as below

```
NSString *name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];
NSString *price = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
```

now I have an NSMutableArray named as Data, I have declared and synthesized it properly, now how can I add values into it, I tried addObject, and print in NSLog, but showing null value, while there are values in name and price?

help me out

Comment: Can you show us more of the code? Also, can you show us the console output you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

If the *array* is `nil`, it will never accept values because it doesn't exist. Even if you synthesize a property, it doesn't mean the property gets a default object assigned to it. Somebody still has to make sure an instance of `NSMutableArray` exists.

Comment: // Status object for Array
    
    //Status *object = [[Status alloc] initWithName:name price:price];
    Status *object = [[Status alloc] init];
    
    //[Data addObject:object];
    
    [Data1 addObject:name];
    [Data2 addObject:price];

    
    [object setArray2: Data1];
    [object release];

Comment: But where do you create these `Data` objects? `Data`, `Data1`, `Data2`--are they supposed to be the same as `Status *object`?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSNumber *WId;
                int temp1 = (int)sqlite3_column_int(walkstatement, 0);
                WId = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:temp1];

                char *WNameCharacter;
                WNameCharacter = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(walkstatement, 1);
                NSString *WNameString = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:WNameCharacter];

NSMutableDictionary *tempWalk = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                [tempWalk setObject:WId forKey:@"WalkId"];
                [tempWalk setObject:WNameString forKey:@"WalkName"];

            [regionWalkArray addObject:tempWalk];
```

This worked for me please change the variables according to your requirement..